# Delete block of rows postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I need to delete a block of rows in a Postgres table. I have a query which cointain the range of uid I have to delete.

For example, as output of my query I have the column uid:

--output--

```
uid 
1
10
55
150
```

I need to the delete the block from uid 1 to uid 9, then from uid 10 to uid 54, then from uid 55 to uid 149 and so on...

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Why not just delete from 1 to 150?

Comment: Are you meaning you desire to delete 1-150 essentially as Gordon commented, or along the lines of (1,9], (10, 54], (55, 149] where you delete all except your boundaries listed?

Comment: postgres version number?

Comment: postgres 9.3. I mean to delete the block from 1 to 10 included. A block could be like this : 1 to 172, block2: 1050 to 1500 and so on..

Comment: I solved by using a cursor and discovered start block and end block

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from tablename
where uid in (
    select uid from yourquery
)
```

Comment: That will not delete rows with  `uid = 2`